# Ext JS data conversion

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

**Store:**

```
Ext.define('firstApp.store.school', {
  model: 'School',
  root: 'children',
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://localhost/firstApp/app/data/school.json',
    reader: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  },
  autoLoad: true
});
```

**Model:**

```
Ext.define('School', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    {name: 'text', type: 'string'}
  ]
});
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "children": [
    {"firstName": "Phil", "lastName": "Potato", "leaf": true },
    {"firstName": "Nico", "lastName": "Potato", "expanded": true, "children": [
      {"firstName": "Mitchell", "lastName": "Potato", "leaf": true }
    ]},
    { "firstName": "Sue", "lastName": "Potato", "leaf": true }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert data from my JSON file into School model by making `text` in model  equal to `firstName + lastName` from JSON. Recently searched for some info, but didn't find any helpful. Can you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`convert`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field-method-convert) for that.

The model:

```
Ext.define('Dude', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'fullname',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'firstname', mapping: 'name.first'},
        {name: 'lastname',  mapping: 'name.last'},
        {name: 'city', defaultValue: 'unknown'},
        'state',
        {name: 'text',  convert: function(v, record){
            !record.data.city ? '' : (record.data.city + ', ' + record.data.state);
        }}
    ]
});
```